# python fetch data from website sub pages

Tags: python, urllib2

I am attempting to create a bot that fetches market links from steam but have run into a problem.  I was able to return all the data from a single page, but when I attempt to get multiple pages it just gives me copies of the first page though I give it working links (eg: http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=appid%3A753#p1 and then http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=appid%3A753#p2).  I have tested the links and they work in my browser.  This is my code.

```
import urllib2
import random
import time

start_url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=appid%3A753"
end_page = 3
urls = []

def get_raw(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return response.read()

def get_market_urls(html):
    index = 0
    while index != -1:
        index = html.find("market_listing_row_link", index+25)
        beg = html.find("http", index)
        end = html.find('"',beg)
        print html[beg:end]
        urls.append(html[beg:end])

def go_to_page(page):
    return start_url+"#p"+str(page)

def wait(min, max):
    wait_t = random.randint(min,max)
    time.sleep(wait_t)

for i in range(end_page):
    url = go_to_page(i+1)
    raw = get_raw(url)
    get_market_urls(raw)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you've misunderstood what the URL says.

The number after the hashtag doesn't mean it's a different URL that can be fetched. This is called the *query string*. In that particular page the query string explains to the javascript which page to pull off AJAX. (Read about it [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) if you're interested..).

Anyway, you shoul look at the url: `http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=appid%3A753&start=00&count=10`. You can play with the start=**00**&count=**10** parameters to get the results you want.

Enjoy.

Comment: I didn't know really where to point him to since these are fairly large subjects of their own and are not in some documentation of python, but I've added some general links. Thanks!

Comment: may be I wasn't clear, I mean documentation about steamcommunity json API, but thanks anyway